# Custom function fails when passing range into it

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script, range, strip

Trying to extract the first word from each cell in a range passed into the custom function. However, getting an error when using the function in the [test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0).

```
/**
* @customfunction
*/
function test(alt_activities_range)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range[0]; 

  var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range.map(str => {
    let arr = str.split(' ');
    return arr[0];
  });

  console.log(alt_activities_array);
  
}
```

The following error is produced:
TypeError: str.split is not a function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the values of "B1:I1" of `=test(B1:I1)` are `[["Chess - 6","Pilates - 6","Elevate - 6","Kundalini - 6","Scrabble - 6","Gardening - 6","Darning - 6","Crossword - 6"]]`. So, in the case of your script, `alt_activities_range` is `[["Chess - 6","Pilates - 6","Elevate - 6","Kundalini - 6","Scrabble - 6","Gardening - 6","Darning - 6","Crossword - 6"]]`.

In your script, the 1st element is retrieved by `var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range[0]`. But, at `var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range.map(str => {`, `alt_activities_range` is used. In this case, it is a 2-dimensional array. By this, `str` is an array. I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue of `TypeError: str.split is not a function.`.

If you want to remove this issue, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range.map(str => {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  return arr[0];
});
```

#### To:

```
var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range[0].map(str => { // or alt_activities_array.map(str => {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  return arr[0];
});
```

- By this modification, `alt_activities_array` is `["Chess","Pilates","Elevate","Kundalini","Scrabble","Gardening","Darning","Crossword"]`.

Comment: @Drew254 Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Yes it did. Sorry for the delay in my response.